# Does VS Express have everything I will need?

Tags: visual-studio

I have to ask this question because I've never programmed except in an intro to C++ class, so my knowledge is extremely limited.

Here's my question.  For me to write a C# program with a SQL Server Express db, does VS Express have everything I'll need to get from start to finish?  If not, what else might I need (and please be specific because I'm new to all of this.)

Thank you.

Update:  Thanks to Malfist, I see I can download full versions due to being a student.  So I guess this question is moot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will [contain enough to get you started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcbsd3cz%28VS.80%29.aspx?ppud=4), the SQL Sever won't be included, you'll have to [download it separately.](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/)

If you're a student with a *.edu email account you can download full editions for free with [DreamSpark](https://www.dreamspark.com/Default.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

When coupled with an external tool to do source control (plenty of free options), it has the bare minimum needed for most projects.  To make sure it's not missing a feature you'll want for *your* project, you should check out this page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcbsd3cz(VS.80).aspx?ppud=4

Note that this is for Visual Studio 2005 - the 2008 editions compare page seems to have gone missing.

Answer (score 1):

At an introductory stage, yes, the express versions will have everything you need to get started writing an application with a database backend.  Check out [MS's introduction here](http://www.microsoft.com/exPress/).  The [limitations are also available here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express).

Answer (score 1):

Together with [Testdriven.net](http://testdriven.net/) and [tortoise svn](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) you've got everything you need to get started very well

Comment: @ChrisC: while it's helpful to explain the reason for a vote, it's not helpful to simply state that the vote occurred. The number next to the answer does that.

Answer (score 0):

As of my experience, if you are going for windows desktop programming, Visual Studio has the most complete and advanced features you can ever find.

I'll recommend also that you get a look at Expression Design (Blend), it'll help you build interactive applications (WPF)and it works with VS Express (but it's not free).

Comment: Thanks.  Upvoted. (I don't see why someone would've downvoted this answer.)  One question about what you said.  What do you mean by "interactive applications (WPF)"?

Comment: this mean beautiful application with customized design, animations... like Flash content. It's called Windows Presentation Foundation and use XAML (little similar to HTML)