# How to add windows console templates in VS Web Dev 2010 Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

How to add windows console  templates in [Visual Web Developer Express 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd537667%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?

I want create projects in c# windows forms applications, code it in same language , when i install 2010 visual express ,windows forms console templates are not visible and not there , How can i start my project ...So please suggest me how to add Windows forms templates in studio ...

[How to add windows form templates to studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gno92.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain whether you're looking for WinForms templates (the old-school GUI stuff), console templates (command-prompt stuff), or something else entirely. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: yes i am looking for winforms templates & console templates , how to add it to my studio ..my studio only visible class library option .. Did u get my point

Comment: Can't you just get [VS Community edition](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx) which will come with almost all possible templates instead of trying to hack templates into MS Visual Web Dev 2010 Express?

Comment: You will have to install a separate VS Express, such as Visual C# Express, so as to get those templates, as simply VWD Express does not support them. Or as @AlexeiLevenkov suggested, switch to VS Community Edition.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does VS Express have everything I will need?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300033/does-vs-express-have-everything-i-will-need)